# Reference instance variables or method call within a class

Tags: java, instance, getter

When using instance variables within a class, is there any advantage to directly referencing the instance variable versus using a getter? Which is more commonly seen?

Example using method calls:

```
public double howMuchFreeSpace() {
    return getCapacity() - getVolume();
```

Example referencing instance variables:

```
public double howMuchFreeSpace() {
    return this.capacity - this.volume;
```

Comment: Depends on what you need them for.

Comment: It makes very little difference performance wise, so mostly a matter of readability and encapsulation.

Comment: I'd prefer direct access since getters risk that the values are read form outside violating  encapsulation...

Answer (score 0):

It's usually matter of preference inside a class. Direct referencing is more readable IMHO. So I suggest using direct referencing unless you need to execute some code when getting the value - that may be a reason to use getter.